# How to get Access token from Linked In android sdk?

Tags: android, linkedin-api, social-authentication

I have given social authentication via Linked In. I have successfully integrated the mobile sdk into my project. Now the question is, how to get access token.

I didn't find any way to fetch access token from sdk.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Add this line to your existing onActivityResult() method
    LISessionManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.i("Access token->", LISessionManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getSession().getAccessToken().getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by calling webview intent for authorization and then on response you can retrieve it in your activity. Just follow the steps:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12405429/5577679

Comment: Answer was asked in 2011. Its too old. Now we have LinkedIn sdk. Why should i go witth webview?

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30080583/android-linkedin-sdk-produces-unusable-access-tokens?rq=1

Comment: LISessionManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getSession().getAccessToken().getValue()

 helps to get access token.

Note: add above line in onActivityResult().